# How can I send an automatic e-mail when any of certain range of cells' value has changed

Tags: excel, vba

How can I write an excel macro which will send an automatic e-mail when one of the certain range of cells' value has been changed?

The problem is the range of cells I have chosen has formula which is directly linked to other spreadsheet cells. And those cells' data has been updated by a web connection query of Excel. As shown in the picture below, the a1:b5 range has formula linked to d1:e5 range.

Here is my syntax

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


    Dim rngChangeCells As Range
    Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strMailBody As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngChangeCells = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("a1:b5"))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngChangeCells Is Nothing Then

        Set objOutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
        Set objMailItem = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        strMailBody = "Cell(s) " & rngChangeCells.Address(False, False) & _
            " in the worksheet '" & Me.Name & "' were modified on " & _
            Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " at " & Format$(Now, "hh:mm:ss") & _
            " by " & Environ$("username") & "."

        With objMailItem
            .To = "myagmarchuluun@gmail.com"
            .Subject = "It has changed"
            .Body = strMailBody
            .Display
        End With

        Set rngChangeCells = Nothing
        Set objOutlookApp = Nothing
        Set objMailItem = Nothing

    End If

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozaGn.png)

Comment: so what is the problem or  error?

Comment: is it that the query refresh isnt triggering the change event?  the query table has an after refresh event `Private Sub q_AfterRefresh(ByVal Success As Boolean)`

Comment: The data on a1:b5 has formula which has linked to other sheet's other cell.

Comment: which is like a1=sheet2$b$1, and if i changed the value of a1 cell by manual, the macro has worked successfully and displayed my e-mail item. But the value of Sheet2$b$1 cell(which has data connection from website) changed, the macro is not working properly :(

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

Note: Change YourMacroName to the name of your macro in the code.
If you want the code to work for another cell or more cells you can change the range in the event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 200 Then
            Call YourMacroName
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Test this example macro to create/display a Outlook mail with a small text message.
You must copy this macro in a standard module and not in the worksheet module, see this page how.

Note: I use .Display in the code to display the mail, you can change that to .Send

Do not forget to change Call YourMacroName to Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook in the Change event.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Cell A1 is changed" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail9.htm